# Jenkins not picking up my settings.xml file. So cant push to artifactory

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

[Jenkins output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHE0T.jpg)
Jenkins not picking up my settings.xml file. So cant push to artifactory.please help with solution.

Expected it to push to artifactory. Not working so far.Also tried uploading the settings.xml file again and again. Still not working. im in a shared jenkins with other people , iam not the admin.it works when i use it on my local host jenkins using the ui to push it. The problem here is that when i use the declarative pipeline on the shared jenkins server. its says that the settings users file doesnt exist. hope someoene can help me solve this issue.

Comment: Where are you uploading the file? I think you need to push it to the .m2 folder of home of `jenkins` user on jenkins host machine. Make sure you are pushing it to right location.

Comment: Please show your Jenkinsfile